# how to use Perl Regx to parse [key=value] if value has multiple data

Tags: regex, perl

I could not solve below problem so I used Perl script to parse 
without regular expression, but I believe there's a regular expression for it.

*Input String* (there's no newline):

```
ObjectAddress=120.146.128.250,ObjectName=psyseds-tt1y,ObjectClass=SCM F5,ObjectDescription=,Aliases=psyseds-tt1y.site.com.,NameService=A,PTR,DynamicDNSUpdate=A,PTR,CNAME
```

*Expected Output*:

```
ObjectAddress=120.146.128.250
ObjectName=psyseds-tt1y
ObjectClass=SCM F5
ObjectDescription=
Aliases=psyseds-tt1y.site.com.
NameService=A,PTR
DynamicDNSUpdate=A,PTR,CNAME
```

I tried some regular expression to parse string, but I failed to parse 
since it has multiple items with `,` separated value. 
For example, NameService has two value A,PTR.

Please help me to build regular expression to parse above.
`(.+?=.*?)` does not pick up multiple values.

Comment: Are the "keys" fixed? Is the order fixed? You can't make a format specification with one example.

Comment: if key name and order fixed, it would be easy :(

Comment: When you want to edit your question, please do so by clicking the "edit" link, *not* by closing the question and opening a new one. (Those with >10k priv, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14733804/978917.)

Comment: @ruakh: oh, were you writing something on that post ? so sorry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it doesn't seem that your format is unambiguous — something like `A=B,C=D` could mean either that `A` maps to `B` and `C` maps to `D`, or that `A` maps to `B,C=D` — but for a good approximation, you can write:

```
my @output = split /,(?=\w+=)/, $input;
```

this will split `$input` on commas (`,`), with the added restriction that the comma must be followed by one or more "word characters" (`\w` — letters, digits, underscores) plus an equals sign. (This is called a [*lookahead assertion*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).)

Comment: +1.  I like this one better than mine.  :)  I was overthinking or something; it's a lot simpler than having to match the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can **match** with this regex

```
(?<=^|,)(?<key>.*?)=(?<value>.*?)(?=,|$)
```

You can now access values by there group names